# MySQL row length more than twice what I expect

Tags: mysql, myisam

In MySQL for a table in this format:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `field1` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `field2` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field3` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field4` datetime NOT NULL,
  `field5` enum('opt1','opt2','opt3','opt4','opt5') NOT NULL,
  `field6` enum('opt1','opt2','opt3','opt4','opt5','opt6') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`field1`),
  KEY `field5` (`field5`),
  KEY `field2` (`field2`),
  KEY `field4` (`field4`),
  KEY `field6` (`field6`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I expect the row length to be 46.

- 32 for char(32)
- 2 for smallint(5)
- 2 for smallint(5)
- 8 for datetime
- 1 for enum
- 1 for enum

But instead the row length is 111 every time I try it. I can't find any explanation for why this is. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UTF8 field that is char(32) will use up to 3 bytes per character.

Comment: Thanks, I had looked at [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) but evidently not really read it. I saw the part that said "Basic Latin letters, digits, and punctuation signs use one byte." but didn't notice the part that said "MySQL must reserve three bytes for each character."

Answer (score 1):

the size of a utf8 char is 3 or 4 bytes in mysql

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing something wrong. It is normal.

Comment: That's not an answer to the *"I can't find any explanation for why this is"*